# On Ubuntu 16.04, running “import tensorflow” generates "ImportError: No module named tensorflow" error

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04 for cpu only with 64 bit machine but when I import tensorflow, an error `"ImportError: No module named tensorflow"`occurs. 
Additional information:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

---

```
~$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/rtm-1/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

How to resolve that?

Comment: Can you describe how you installed tensorflow? It seems that you are using Anaconda. Is that possible you've installed tensorflow in an environment (like "tensorflow") but forgot to activate it when trying to use tensorflow?

Comment: Have you installed TF from sources or PIP? E.g. `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed tensorflow after or before creating the environment?

Each Ancaonda environment has its independednt Python modules, so if you created the enviornment after installing, then it wouldn't import it.